# Plotting a sum of Bessel functions

Tags: plotting, special-functions, summation

I would like to plot the Nth partial sum, given τ for different values of "n". I'm really new at this so i don't even know how to begin. I have to make a graph of ξ vs ϕ and find the minimum of n so i can describe the profile accurately. ξ and τ are supposed to be between [0,1]. I would like to plot this for n=5,10. Also i found this problem in the book Transport Phenomena in chapter 4.
Please help me!

[image]

Where αn is the nth zero of the 0th order Bessel function

I put some parts of codes, and this is the best that ive got ( i made x=ξ, just so i can write it easily)

[image]

This is what the book gives, where vz/vzmax is ϕ, vt/R^2 is τ and r/R is ξ. You are supposed to adimentionalize the variables, so that is why it is changed.
[image]

Comment: And what is $\alpha_n$ supposed to be?

Comment: In addition to Nasser's request, it would be nice if you could give a reference (book/paper/etc.) where you encountered this sum.

Comment: Where αn is the nth zero of the 0th order Bessel function. I would like to plot this for n=5,10.
I managed to scavenge some codes an put this together, this is the best that i've got:

ClearAll["Global`*"]
An[n_] := 1/((BesselJZero[0, n])^3 BesselJ[1, BesselJZero[0, n]])
function[x_, max_] := (1 - x^2) - 8*Sum[An[n] BesselJ[0, BesselJZero[0, n] x], {n, max}]
Plot[function[x, 10], {x, 0, 1}]

Comment: I found this exercise in the book Transport Phenomena by Bird, Steward and Lightfoot. It is the 4D.2 exercise. The solution show's the graph, but i dont know how they plotted it

Comment: May be you can scan the page that shows the equations and the plot you wanted generated and paste the image in your post. Also, the code you put in your comment does not match the latex shown. you code does not have $\tau$ and does not have $\xi$.

Comment: I just edited the question, i added the code that i made. I dont really now how to write the code in the comments so i just copied and pasted it

Comment: what is range of $\xi$ and $\tau$ to use? Please do not let people guess.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this additional information, instead of just leaving it in comments.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Maybe now is more explicit?

Comment: I do not understand the x-axis in your plot. From 1 to zero, then goes again from zero to 1?

Comment: Yes, it is not really an acurate plot. It's based mostly in physics more than mathematics, so that is why. The book just does it that way.

Comment: The code you show in your post is not the same as the formula you show. You are missing $\xi$ in your `An` definition, which you called `x` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Here is the code.

[image]

### Code

```
(*precompute BesselJ zeros. Much faster this way*)
zeros = Table[N@BesselJZero[0, n], {n, 1, 10}]; 

ϕ[ξ_?NumericQ, τ_?NumericQ, max_] := (1 - ξ^2) - 
  8 Sum[α = zeros[[n]]; 
      BesselJ[0, α ξ]/(α^3* BesselJ[1, α ξ]) Exp[- α^2 τ ], {n, 1, max}];


Manipulate[
 Quiet@Plot[ϕ[ξ, τ, max], {ξ, 0, 1},
  AxesLabel -> {"ξ", "ϕ(ξ)"},
  BaseStyle -> 12,
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"Using τ=", τ}],
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
  PlotStyle -> Red
  ],
 {{τ, .3, "τ"}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{max, 3, "number of terms?"}, 2, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {τ, max}
 ]
```

### Animation

[image]

### Alternative

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Quiet@Plot[
   Evaluate[ϕ[ξ, #, max] & /@ Range[0.3, 0.9, 0.1]], {ξ, 
    0, 1},
   AxesLabel -> {"ξ", "ϕ(ξ)"},
   BaseStyle -> 12, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"Using τ=", Range[0.3, 0.9, 0.1]}],
   GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray],
 {{max, 3, "number of terms?"}, 2, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ContinuousAction -> True, TrackedSymbols :> {τ, max}]
```